# Построение графика результата функции value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

У меня есть результат следующий функции:

```
df_1['product_name'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x > 5]
df_1


тапки одноразовые                      277
плавки мужские плавательные            103
шапка войлок взрослая                   51
пружинки для волос                      40
шапка войлок модельная                  17
гель для душа                           15
набор шампунь и кондиционер Sargan      14
пантолеты женские пляжные ЭВА           13
шапка детская Лошадка, Рога             13
шапочка для плавания                    11
пантолеты мужские пляжные ЭВА           11
маска белая глина 100 г                 10
чехол со шнурком                        10
шапка войлок детская                     8
шапочка травяная                         7
краб для волос                           6
Name: product_name, dtype: int64
```

Как я могу построить эти данные в виде графика?
Пробовал через:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(s['product_name'])
```

Но не видит столбца в "s".

Также пробовал через:

```
b = df_1['product_name'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x > 5]
plt.bar(b.index, b.values)
```

Тут всё получилось, но подписей данных не видно. Хотелось бы получить результат через seaborn.

Comment: что такое `s` у вас? и почему вы решили использовать countplot, а не barplot?

Comment: `countplot` нужно применять к исходному датафрейму, он сам посчитает что-то типа `value_counts` для отрисовки

Comment: @strawdog, прошу прощения, это была переменная "b".

Answer (score 1):

если вы получаете результат в виде серии, то рисуйте график так:

```
sns.barplot(data=s, orient="h")
```

где s - ваша серия с результатом выполнения value_counts().

Если у вас результат получен в виду датафрейма, то делаете то же самое, но с явным указанием колонок данных:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x=1, y=0, orient="h")
```

где x - колонка со значениями, y - с наименованием товаров

получите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну и слово "однаразовые" исправьте на "одноразовые".

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно без `Seaborn` и вообще без явного импорта графических библиотек, но будет не такой красивый график:

```py
s = df_1['product_name'].value_counts()
s[s>5].plot(kind='barh')
```